# How to get a reference to a control from its' string name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, controls, visual-web-developer

How to get a reference to a control from its' string name in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Page.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx)

If the Control is nested, use `Control.FindControl` from the parent Control. Otherwise, you'll have to write your own [FindControlRecursive](https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/)

Comment: Note: In collections of controls, the FindControl method will return a different instance of the control of that name. In ASP.NET, that control will have a unique name also. In other words, FindControlRecursive will return the 1st control of that name.

Answer (score 1):

```
        private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
        {
            return root.ID == id
                       ? root
                       : (root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                             .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id)))
                             .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);
        }
```