# Using the value of a variable to set the visiblity of a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello all I am slowly learning c#, and I have this problem:

I want to make a function that sets all panels not visible and then set one as visible given to me from a string variable.

```
public void setMeVisible(string PanelName)
{
    PageMainScreen.Visible = false;

    PageNewRegistration.Visible = false;

    PageSelectedPatient.Visible = false;

    ["PanelName"].Visible = true;  // in this line I want to set the value of
    //  PanelName.Visible=true.
    // what is the format that I must put PanelName?
}
```

Comment: luckly there is no eval in c# :D

Comment: [windows solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/c-sharp-get-control-by-name)

Comment: @Liam for the win! :)

Comment: Apologies, the PanelName WILL contain a panel name 100%, I will have put it myself, so if the new registration button is pressed all I write is
setMEVisible(PAgeNewRegistration).


My question is: I have string  a variable PanelName how do I set that panel visible? It Windows. Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Page.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) for ASP.Net:

```
var control = FindControl(PanelName);
if (control != null)
    control.Visible = true;
```

If your control is nested, you can create a FindControlRecursive function, suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835538/724591):

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    return root.ID == id
               ? root
               : (root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                     .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id)))
                     .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);
}
```

Then call it by doing:

```
var control = FindControlRecursive(form1, PanelName); // Or another top-level control other than form1
if (control != null)
    control.Visible = true;
```

Use [Controls.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-c-sharp-winforms-by-name) for a windows form application:

```
var control = Controls.Find(PanelName, true).FirstOrDefault();
if (control != null)
    control.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, The simplest way is loop through all the controls and check if its a panel and set it to false. In the same loop you can check panel.Name for the pass in "PanelName" and set it to true. Something like this

```
foreach(Control control in form.Controls)
{
    if( control is Panel )
    {
       control.Visible = false;
       if(control.Name == "PanelName")
           control.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: What if said Panel(s) are nested in a container **other** than the Form?...what if they are all in different containers?  Then you'd need a **Recursive** search.

Answer (score 1):

Looping and finding controls is not really necessary. You should add all your panels to a same container, use the `Controls` collection and pass in the name to get the control:

```
public void setMeVisible(string PanelName) {
  PageMainScreen.Visible = false;
  PageNewRegistration.Visible = false;
  PageSelectedPatient.Visible = false;
  Control c = sameContainer.Controls[PanelName];
  if(c != null) c.Visible = true;
}
```

If each time there is only 1 panel visible, you should use some variable to track the current shown panel and hide only this (instead of all controls as you did) like this:

```
Control currentShown;
public void setMeVisible(string PanelName) {
  Control c = sameContainer.Controls[PanelName];
  if(c != null) {
     c.Visible = true;
     if(currentShown != null) currentShown.Visible = false;
     currentShown = c;
  }
}
```

And the last, if you don't want to use the same container for all your panels. You should declare some `List<Panel>` to contain all your panels, then you can navigate through them easily:

```
List<Panel> panels = new List<Panel>();
panels.AddRange(new[]{PageMainScreen, PageNewRegistration, PageSelectedPatient});
public void setMeVisible(string PanelName) {
  var c = panels.FirstOrDefault(panel=>panel.Name == PanelName);
  if(c != null) {
     c.Visible = true;
     if(currentShown != null) currentShown.Visible = false;
     currentShown = c;
  }      
}
```

**NOTE**: Don't try complicating your UI unnecessarily. I want to mean that **you should place all your panels on the same container** (such as your form). That's the way we do, that way you can use the first approach, no need to loop, easy to maintain. You should also consider the `Dock` and the methods like `BringToFront()` and `SendToBack()` to show/hide the view.